# Why is my ASP.NET Web API route working with Postman but not working with Angular Post request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, rest

I have no idea what's going on here. I have a POST route using ASP.NET web API that should change some data in my SQL Server. When I use Postman to test out my REST API it works and the data is changed in the database and the response is okay. But once I use Angular5 to post json to the same database it responds with error 405. Here is my code...

First, here is the POST route from my MVC app.

```
// POST api/<controller>
[Route("")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]BranchesInfo data)
{
    BranchesDB.updateBranchRow(data);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<BranchesInfo>(HttpStatusCode.OK,data);
    return response;
}
```

The response from Postman is in the next image. The data is successfully changed in the database although it has no correlation to the info being sent in as my Stored Procedure that's called in the updateBranchRow() function does not respond with any resource, so I made up the resource to return the same data passed in.

Here you can see that the request is recieved and works successfully in PostMan

[image]

Now, here is my Angular code which uses a service to post the data.

```
host: string = "http://localhost:57440/api/branches";

updateBranch(branchKey: Number, mainBranch: String, branchRegion: String, mainBranchFlag: Boolean) {
  var data = {
    BranchKey: branchKey,
    BranchName: mainBranch,
    BranchRegion: branchRegion,
    MainBranchFlag: mainBranchFlag
  }
  return this.http.post(this.host, data).map(res => res.json());
});
```

And here is an image of the error I am getting on the browser console once I try to log the response recieved.

Response on the browser console:

[image]

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. How can a REST based request work with Postman but not work when using Angular4??

Comment: You need to enable cors on your api.

Comment: See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Postman might be using your browser's "settings" which may include any CORS plugin. I recommend you re-create your post using an 
"independent" tool like cURL and paste the results.

Comment: It's not angular, it's your browser which cares about CORS and fires an OPTIONS request before a POST. The OPTIONS isn't handled in your API so it returns an error so the browser doesn't do the POST.

Comment: So how do I make my browser not do that?

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: All modern browsers do that and it can't be disabled. It is up to the API to add support for it. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api The browser sees it is a Cross Origin request, it adds the headers and then it expects a matching response from the API. No matching response means the browser blocks the response.

Comment: @Onejohi_ Can you post your controller code ? are you running this code from IIS?

Comment: @Niladri, yes I am running from IIS. The controller code is the first code segment. I have enabled CORS in my web.config file to accept GET, PUT, POST, DELETE and OPTIONS. Access Control Allow Origin is set to * as well in the web.config file

Comment: @Onejohi_ but your API method accepts POST only and the browser sends a preflight OPTIONS request to it so it returns the 405 method not allowed. Can you add  `<system.webServer>` section of your web.config .. the <modules> and <handlers> part

Comment: @Onejohi_ also did you try adding `content-type` : application/json request header to your HTTP post in angular

Comment: @Niladri, I've received my answer. Thanks so much for your help anyways. You guys are the best!

Comment: @Niladri, yes I had set up application/json request header. It seems the Application_BeginRequest function was to catch an Options method from the browser to let the request through.

Comment: it's strange but I did face same issue in IIS due to the WebDAV module .. so i had to remove it from web.config

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Global.asax.cs file add following code

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm!! I would soooooo upvote your answer but I'm at 9 points and my vote won't count till I get to 15. But thank you soooo much, you just solved a problem that's wasted half of my day.

Comment: I am glad to help you :-)

Comment: Note: for an older Asp.Net 4.7 project, this is the only thing that worked. Also add the settings in the web.config 
   <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
     <clear />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
    </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>

Answer (score 0):

Postman does not send a XmlHttp Request. With postman you're manually interacting with a site so that you have full control. However in your web application  you are making a Cross Origin Request.You need to enable CORS in your Api.
 You can read more about CORS in Asp.Net Web API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

Comment: I have this to enable CORS in my web.config

Comment: <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

Comment: @Onejohi_ Look here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors