# 500 (Internal Server Error) on http.post in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

My service function:

```
public postDetails(Details): Observable<any> {
    let cpHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cpHeaders });
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/api/adm/Dtls", Details,options)
        .map((res: any) => { 
            let data = res.json();
            return data; })
}
```

TS file.

```
let postdata:any= JSON.stringify(Details);
        
        this.data = this.storageservice.postDetails(postdata);
        this.data.subscribe((result: any) => {
            if (result) {
               console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

Error on Browser

```
 OPTIONS http://10.23.233.45/statapi/api/details/Dtls 500 (Internal Server Error)
     Failed to load http://10.23.233.45/statapi/api/details/Dtls: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500.
    core.js:1448 ERROR Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}
```

I am able to post the data using Postman, but I am not able to send data through angular, I have no clue what's the issue.

Comment: It's a CORS issue, make sure your backend handles OPTIONS request  and returns a 200 http code

Comment: are you using .net web api?

Comment: HI Parth, yes i am using .net web api. below i am using in web.config.

  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

Comment: Recently I just gave answer to this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673496/why-is-my-asp-net-web-api-route-working-with-postman-but-not-working-with-angula/49674035#49674035](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673496/why-is-my-asp-net-web-api-route-working-with-postman-but-not-working-with-angula/49674035#49674035)

Answer (score 0):

Your service does not handle [CORS Preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Modern browsers use CORS to enhance security. Non-browser apps (like Postman) don't. In order to make it work, make the webservice respond to `OPTIONS` requests with proper CORS headers and 200 status code.

Comment: Cianciolo, I have added Options and post as well.. but still the same issue

Comment: Reading from your question, the response to a `OPTIONS` request returned HTTP code 500. That's exactly the problem.