# C# Web API 2 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I have an existing deployed web application using `Angular` and `C# Web API 2` which was working before. I didn't know when it started but I recently added a new feature and after that I've been getting the error `405 Method Not Allow` for all my `PUT` actions.

I'm not sure which technology this is related to so I'm tagging all the technology i've used.

Any idea why and how to resolve this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

**I forgot to mention that everything is working fine locally, I only get this error when it is already published to server.**

**Also that my Angular project is inside the Web API project so I think there'd be no issue with `CORS`, right?**

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what configuration changes you have done for this new feature development?

Comment: That's the thing, there are no config changes as far as web.config or IIS is concerned. Just additional c# controllers and Angular module.

Comment: Have you tried adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521656/9766215) in your web.config?

Comment: @Prachi which web.config? there are two of them.

Comment: The one which resides in the folder where your API project is present. The outer most one.

Comment: This Might [Help](https://enable-cors.org/server.html)

Comment: why you are not try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673496/why-is-my-asp-net-web-api-route-working-with-postman-but-not-working-with-angula/49674035#49674035

Comment: please share your web.config at the api project ... also the action method with HttpPut and how are you calling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC-Web API: 405 method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293782/mvc-web-api-405-method-not-allowed)

Comment: I don't think it's a CORS issue. Please check i've updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, there was WebDAV iis module that blocks some http verbs.
You can disable it for your web application

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/webdav/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

[Asp.NET Web API - 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed - how to set handler mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854602/asp-net-web-api-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-how)

Webdav has to be uninstalled, disabling it doesn't work.